# library for client-side events (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, web-services

anyone knows some good libraries to implement client-side events which are created by the server?
e.g.
Client starts an action over webservice and then server send events to the client when the state has changed.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout is free open source client side library.

It might be worth taking a look to

http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

`Http` currently relies on `Request/Response` so once you get the response back from the web service you cannot trabsfer more information of which event to raise
i think what you want here is `Sockets` so that once connected you can transfer data multiple times from server to client and client can take decisions accordingly
1 library of sockets that i use is `SignalR` though it uses LongPolling but switches to sockets when they are available